# Does anyone have a LaTeX template for Hydrological Processes (Wiley)?

Tags: templates, journal

The journal "Hydrological Processes" (Wiley) accepts LaTeX manuscripts, but appears not to have a template, as some other journals do. Does anyone have a template that may be suitable? I assume that it will use `natbib` for the bibliography.

Comment: Have checked site - even emailed wiley, but cannot find any indication of a latex template?

Answer (score 3):

Just use article. But be warned that although HP will accept a single pdf for review, if it is conditionally accepted (even with major revisions) they ask for text-and-equations Word format with publication-ready figures in tif and eps/pdf format. No mention of Latex. Very annoying.